# Sequelize - One to Many relationship lazy load and return one instance and not a collection

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Looking for a way to lazy load a hasMany relationship but only return one instance of the relationship instead of a collection.

Desired Output

```
{
  id: 5,
  note: 'Hello World',
  date: '2019-10-12',
}
```

Output I am getting

```
[
  {
    id: 5,
    note: 'Hello World',
    date: '2019-10-12',
  }
]
```

The code I have currently is

```
....
const note = await user.getNotes({
  limit: 1,
  where: {
    date: moment('2019-10-12')
  }
});
```

Is there a way when lazy loading to get just one instance of that note back as opposed to having to use `note[0]` after loading that relationship.

Comment: i think you have to try `belongsto` relation it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to deconstruct the array and set the value of `note` to the first element:

```js
const [ note ] = await user.getNotes({
  limit: 1,
  where: {
    date: moment('2019-10-12')
  }
});
```

You can also use `Note.findOne()` and pass in the `user.id` to the `where` clause. Internally this is doing effectively the same thing as above.

```js
const note = await Note.findOne({
  limit: 1,
  where: {
    user_id: user.id,
    date: moment('2019-10-12')
  }
});
```